# Javascript fetch API and PHPMailer slow response

Tags: javascript, php, fetch, phpmailer

When a customer orders a product they send a form to the server side. I validate the form in php, and if there are no errors I send and e-mail to the customer and one e-mail to myself, containing the product informations which is received from the form. I use PHPMailer to send the e-mails, but it is rather slow, it takes like 5 seconds to send the mails and get back the response from the server to javascript. When I take out the code which sends the emails, the response arrives immediately. The PHPMailer slows the response, but I don' know why.

Javascript:

```
 const form = document.querySelector("#form");
      form.addEventListener("submit", (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        const formData = new FormData(form);
        fetch("index.php", {
          method: 'post',
          body: formData
        }).then((resp) => resp.json())
        .then(function (text) {
          console.log(text); //Do something with the response, which is an array
          if(text !== undefined && text.length > 0) { //The array isn't empty
            //Show errors
            const formdiverror = document.querySelector(".col-100-form-error");
            const colform = document.querySelector(".col-100-form");
            colform.style.display = "block";
            formdiverror.innerHTML = "";
            text.forEach(t => formdiverror.innerHTML += t + "</br>");
          } else {
            //array is empty, no errors
             const colform = document.querySelector(".col-100-form");
             if(colform !== null || colform !== undefined) colform.style.display = "none";
             alert("Success!");
             window.location.replace("index.html"); //if there was no error redirect to index.html
          }
        });
      })
```

PHP:

```
<?php
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer;
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\SMTP;
require 'Exception.php';
require 'PHPMailer.php';
require 'SMTP.php';

$errors = [];

if(isset($_POST["name"]) && isset($_POST["address"]) && isset($_POST["email"]))  {
    $name = $_POST["name"];
    $address = $_POST["address"];
    $email = $_POST["email"];

    //I skipped the validation for shorter code
    if(empty($name)) {
        $errors[] = "Name cannot be empty!";
    }

    if(empty($address)) {
        $errors[] = "Address cannot be empty!";
    }


    if (!empty($errors)) {
        echo json_encode($errors); //Sending back the array of string errors
    } else {
        $mail = new PHPMailer();
        $mail->CharSet = "UTF-8";
        $contentBody = '<html><body><div  style="text-align:center; width: 500px; display:block; margin-left: auto; 
        margin-right: auto;"><p style="text-align:center;"><h2>' . $name . ' ' . $address . '</div></body></html>';

        //Sending to client
        $mail->setFrom("mymail@gmail.com", "MyName"); //Who is sending the message
        $mail->addAddress($email); //Set who the message is to be sent to
        $mail->AddReplyTo("mymail@gmail.com", "MyName");
        $mail->Subject = 'Order';
        $mail->isHTML(TRUE);
        $mail->Body = $contentBody;
        $mail->isSMTP();
        $mail->Host = 'smtp.gmail.com';
        $mail->SMTPAuth = TRUE;
        $mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls';
        $mail->Username = "mymail@gmail.com";
        $mail->Password = 'mypassword';
        $mail->Port = 587;
        if(!$mail->Send())
        {
            echo "Something went wrong!";
        }
        $mail2 = new PHPMailer();
        $mail2->CharSet = "UTF-8";
        //Sending to myself
        $contentBodyForFirm = '<html><body><div  style="text-align:center; width: 500px; display:block; margin-left: auto; 
        margin-right: auto;"><p style="text-align:center;"><h2>' . $name . ' ' . $address . '</div></body></html>';

        $mail2->setFrom($email, $name); //Who is sending the message
        $mail2->addAddress("mymail@gmail.com"); //Set who the message is to be sent to
        $mail2->Subject = 'Order';
        $mail2->isHTML(TRUE);
        $mail2->Body = $contentBodyForFirm;
        $mail2->isSMTP();
        $mail2->charSet = "UTF-8";
        $mail2->Host = 'smtp.gmail.com';
        $mail2->SMTPAuth = TRUE;
        $mail2->SMTPSecure = 'tls';
        $mail2->Username = "mymail@gmail.com";
        $mail2->Password = 'mypassword';
        $mail2->Port = 587;
        if(!$mail2->Send())
        {
            echo "Something went wrong!";
        }
        echo json_encode([]); //Sendning back an empty array

    }
}

?>
```

If there are errors in the validation I use `echo json_encode($errors);` to send back the errors and show them on the client side. If there are no errors I use `echo json_encode([]);`. In javascript I check the fetch response. If it is an empty array there were no errors, and I can redirect to index.html.

Comment: Do you know if it's slow because of your code or perhaps something else? I'd take a close look at the network tab in your browser first, to see if it's not something else. In the network tab, click the request and then subtab 'Timing' (in Chrome at least)

Comment: @paddotk I checked it, here are the details:
Resource Scheduling: Queueing 2.51ms
Connection Start: Stalled 1.07ms
Request/Response: 
Request sent 0.18ms
Waiting (TTFB) 3.95s
Content Download: 1.10ms

Explanation: 3.95s

Comment: I'm not sure about this, but to me it looks like the 'Waiting' happens after the request is sent; i.e. waiting for the server to respond. In which case it's not related to your code.

Comment: @paddotk Maybe it has an issue with the recent server change. Thank you anyways.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is mostly likely because SMTP is often slow (sometimes deliberately so), especially when talking to remote servers. Sending during page/request processing is not suited to SMTP at all, though that doesn't stop many people doing it.

The best way to make it *much* faster is to relay via a local mail server. This way there is no network overhead and response times will be very fast – you should have no problem sending hundreds of messages *per second*. It will also deal with queuing, throttling, retries, etc for you.

The PHPMailer wiki has [notes on how to send to lists efficiently](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/wiki/Sending-to-lists), which also mostly apply whenever you're sending > 1 message. Take a look at the [list sending example](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/blob/master/examples/mailing_list.phps), which embodies this advice. In your case you're creating a second instance of PHPMailer to send a second message. You're better off re-using the same instance for a second message and using keepalive, which reduces connection overhead considerably.

Comment: If i use a local mail server, do I need to run my computer 0/24?

Comment: No, just while you’re sending and a little while afterwards.

Comment: But the problem is that I don't know when the clients will order.. The e-mail sending should be automatic.

Comment: So get a server? It’s what they are for! If you have a web server it can work as a mail server too.

Comment: The probelm is that I'm doing this for a friend who only has an admin access to the webpage where he can upload snippet of codes. Also i'm not very familiar with server side programming. Before using the fetch API I used Jquery's POST method, and then I had no issues with the waiting. Is it possible the the jquery's method is faster than the fetch api?

Comment: I think you’re going to have to live with it. There will be no appreciable difference between jQuery and fetch. Alternatively, get a proper server from somewhere like scaleway; it only costs about $3/ month.